# Problem setting bucketMaxSpanSeconds and bucketRoundingSeconds for MongoDB timeseries collection

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I am using MongoDB version 7.0.2 (upgraded from 6.0.3) which offers the feature of setting `bucketMaxSpanSeconds` and `bucketRoundingSeconds` according to the official [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/timeseries/timeseries-granularity/). But when I execute the following commands:

```
db.createCollection( "weather24h", { timeseries: { timeField: "timestamp", metaField: "metadata", bucketMaxSpanSeconds: 300, bucketRoundingSeconds: 300 } } )
```

I am getting the error:

`Timeseries 'bucketMaxSpanSeconds' is not configurable to a value other than the default of 3600 for the provided granularity`

Can it be due to the upgrade? Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you [upgrade the FCV value](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/release-notes/7.0-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible--features.) for the database as well?